# How to Parse JavaScript with jsoup

Tags: javascript, java, android, jsoup

In a HTML page, i want to pick the value of a javascript variable. Below is the snippet of HTML page.

```html
<script id="page-data">
    var __IS_MIRA__;
    var __INITIAL_STATE__ = undefined;
    var __CACHE_REGISTRY__ = undefined;
    var __NEXT_CACHE_ID__ = undefined;
    var __DMP_CONFIG__ = {"context":{"access_token":null,"ad_sync_script_url":"http:\/\/www.taolao.com\/cdn\/manifest\/video\/x7775n8.m3u8?auth=1498553714-2562-k2kou1s3-7be1a0645b68824508f7f4989900d487yk2kou1s3&bs=1","admin":false,"as_number":"AS18403","user":null}
```

My aim is to read the value of variable **DMP_CONFIG** from this page using jsoup. Is it possible with jsoup? if yes then how?

And this is my Java code.

```js
  Document doc = Jsoup.connect(""+urlhtml).get();
                Element div = doc.getElementById("page-data");
                Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?is) __DMP_CONFIG__ = \"(.+?)\""); // Regex for the value of the key
                Matcher m = p.matcher(div.html());
                while( m.find() ) {
                    mData =m.group(1);
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you should use Regular Expression to match the group result.

```
ad_sync_script_url":"([^"]+)"
```

Sample code as below:

```
String REGEX = "ad_sync_script_url":"([^"]+)"";

  Pattern r = Pattern.compile(REGEX);
  Matcher m = r.matcher("String that you want to match");   // get a matcher object

  if(m.find()){
    String matchValue = m.group(0);
    String result = matchValue.Replace("\"","");
  }else{
      //doesn't match result.
  }
```

Hope this help :)